# Ajax can not send a request other than GET

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I just can not. For 4 days I have been struggling to send data ajax using a different method than GET and I can not advise. I create a project in Spring Boot. I have created a mapped address controller

```
@PutMapping(value = "/changeEmail")
public boolean changeEmail(
    @RequestBody ChangeEmailDTO changeEmailDTO
) {
    System.out.println("email: " + changeEmailDTO.getEmail());
    return true;
}
```

This controller is supposed to accept the email address sent by ajaxa

```
function changeEmail() {
    console.log("Event");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/changeEmail',
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('function');
        }
    });
}
```

However, the only effect is that in the console crashes me

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/signIn net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
send    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
changeEmail @   settings.js:58
submitHandler   @   settings.js:52
d   @   jquery.validate.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   jquery.validate.min.js:4
dispatch    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

The DTO has only one field

```
public class ChangeEmailDTO {
    @IsValidEmail
    @ExistsEmail(ifExistsReturn = false)
    @Getter @Setter private String email;
}
```

After trying to send data via ajax, it sends me to the error controller

```
@Controller
public class PageNotFoundController implements ErrorController{
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ModelAndView showPageError() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/signIn");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Screen with browser tool what to send and receive: https://zapodaj.net/f1b8ed0b2a16b.png.html
As I mentioned, the controller can correctly pick up a GET query from ajax only. Every time it flips on the error controller.
Additionally, they say that if I wanted to send data directly from the form, then there is no problem with any query.
What this ajax divert, I do not know.

Comment: what is the annotation of your controller , controller or rest controller?

Comment: @Rest Controller

Comment: you are running your spring application on port 8080?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: try in your ajax request url: 'http://localhost:8080/changeEmail',

Comment: Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/changeEmail. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: ok glad that solves your issue , now you need to enable the CORS in your server, you can look up this on google

Comment: I added @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/changeEmail") , but it does not work.

Comment: Anything relevant in the application's logs ?  Spring may log some WARN/ERROR logs according to your configuration.

Comment: There are no logs.

Comment: Maybe you need to add something in the Spring Boot configuration?

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, some logs are automatically displayed in the standard output. 
You should [read this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) to set a logging configuration (for example, you can write logs into a file).

Comment: This appears in logs when sending: https://pastebin.com/RhUXiz7K